# mocha, chai, Uncaught AssertionError: expected {} to equal {} + expected - actual

Tags: mocha.js, chai

```
  it('GET /customers/ with wrong id', (done) => {
    request
      .get(`/customers/${wrongId}`)
      .end((err, res) => {
        expect(res.body).to.equals({});
        expect(res).to.have.status(404);
        done();
      });
  });
```

1) Customers CRUD GET /customers/ with wrong id:

```
  Uncaught AssertionError: expected {} to equal {}
  + expected - actual
```

Answer (score 63):

You want to use [`deep`](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_deep) if you're trying to compare objects:

```
expect(res.body).to.deep.equal({});
```

Or use the [`eql`](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_eql) method:

```
expect(res.body).to.eql({});
```